# calculate a limit on infinity/infinity

Tags: limits

I'm trying to prove $g(n)=o(f(n))$

where $f(n)=2^{n/2},g(n)=\lg(n)^{\lg(n)}$

The solution is as follows:

$f(n)=e^{\ln(2^\frac{n}{2})},g(n)=e^{\lg(n)\ln(\lg(n))}$

Let $a=\frac{n}{2}\ln(2)$ and $b=\lg(n)\ln(\lg(n))$

Since $lim_{n->\infty}\frac{b}{a}=0$ (I'll omit this step)

Then $lim_{n->\infty}(b-a)=-\infty$

Finally $lim_{n->\infty}\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=lim_{n->\infty}e^{b-a}=e^{-\infty}=0$

So $g(n)=o(f(n))$

I'm trying to do it in a direct way but I'm stuck:

Let $t=\lg(n)$ so $n=2^t$

$n\rightarrow\infty\Rightarrow t\rightarrow \infty$

$lim_{n->\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=lim_{t->\infty}\frac{\sqrt2^{2^t}}{t^t}$

So I want to show $lim_{t->\infty}\frac{\sqrt2^{2^t}}{t^t}=\infty$

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{t \to {\infty}} {{\sqrt{2}^{2^t}} \over {t^t}}$$

Can be rewritten as,

$$\lim_{t \to {\infty}} {{2^{2^t/2}} \over {t^t}}$$

Which is equivalent to,

$$L=\lim_{t \to {\infty}} {{2^{2^{t-1}}} \over {t^t}}$$

Assume that $L$ is finite and take the logarithm. We get,

$$\ln(L)=\lim_{t \to {\infty}} \left(2^{t-1} \cdot \ln(2)-t\cdot\ln(t)\right)$$

Which is clearly divergent in the positive direction. This implies that $L$ cannot be finite. Thus, the assumption on $L$ is false and the limit doesn't exist.